# PHP if string contains an <a> tag

Tags: php, html, tags, detection, rel

Let's say I submit a form with the message:

`Hi! What's up? <a href="http://test.com">Click here</a> to check out <a href="http://test.com">my</a> website.`

How can detect if the string contains `<a>` tags with PHP, and then add `rel="nofollow"` to it? So it would change to:

`Hi! What's up? <a href="http://test.com" rel="nofollow">Click here</a> to check out <a href="http://test.com" rel="nofollow">my</a> website.`

A little speculation of how the code would function?

```
$string = $_POST['message'];

if (*string contains <a> tags*) {
    *add rel="nofollow"*
}
```

Comment: Use jquery and submit your form using ajax.

Answer (score 3):

There's always the DOMDocument object.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<a href="http://example.com">woo! examples!</a>');
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $item) {
  $item->setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow'); 
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```